# Script Bash Curl with loop for few files inside folders

Tags: curl

i know there is a lot of subject about this but my problem is different every time.

I need to store several files in local who are in several folders.

- Example : the first path is : myWebsite/Myfolder/dateOfToday/File
- Next one : myWebsite/Myfolder2/dateOfToday/file
- After : myWebsite/Myfolder3/dateOfToday/file

I want to use a script bash with curl but I'm novice.

So I would like to write a script who save each file in a local repository every day.

Thanks for your answers. have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# get todays date
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
# directory of site
site_dir='myWebsite'

# loop through the existing directories to find the highest numbered directory
for dir in $(ls myWebsite)
do
    number=$(echo $dir | sed 's/Myfolder//')
    if [[ "${number}" -gt "${highest}" ]]; then
        high_number="${number}"
    fi
done

# add 1 to the highest number we found
# this will be the number of the new directory we create
new_high_number=$((high_number+1))

# build our new path
new_path=""${site_dir}"/Myfolder"${new_high_number}"/"${today}"/"

# create the dir
mkdir -p "${new_path}"

# curl your file and put it in the new directory
curl -i "${new_path}" http://some-site.com/some-file.json
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for this answer. it will be great. Just some change. Thank you